# Convert Tablet into idiot-proof PC monitor

Tags: tablet, external-display, kiosk-mode

I'm working on a new classroom space at a small college. The goal is to have a fully wireless lecturn for the instructor. That includes power cables: everything must be battery powered. This means sticking all the powered A/V equipment (especially the PC) off to the side, where it can be plugged in, and only including what is effectively a terminal on the podium.

What does that have to do with Android? I'm glad you asked. I still need a display for the lecturn. I need a small-ish screen that can run on a battery for several hours at a time that I can connect over wireless to a PC. I'd prefer a dedicated monitor product, but since I can't find that anywhere, an Android tablet sounds perfect.

So here's the question: how can I set up an android tablet to do this?

I know there are a number of apps out there that support this at a basic level, but just the app alone is not enough. I need the result to be really idiot-proof. If at all possible, I want people to be fooled into thinking that the tablet is nothing more than a monitor: they wake up the tablet and the PC screen comes up with no additional touches, even if no one is logged into the PC yet. This also needs to function as (in some instances) the *only* monitor for the PC. Kiosk support of some type would be ideal, as well.

For what it's worth, I'm also exploring using a UPS (with the alarm disabled) with a traditional display and wireless dongle, but the android solution just seems much more elegant.

Comment: I am aware that this is _partially_ a product recommendation, which would be off-topic, because a specific app or tablet make/model recommendation may come out of this question. However, I believe this question goes beyond the typical product recommendation, in that I'm also looking for instructions on how to set things up, and would accept and encourage answers that support several of the various screen apps and several tablet makes/models.

Comment: Raw idea: Kiosk-Mode (I've just added that tag to your question, so you can check related content) together with some remote-desktop app?

Comment: @Izzy I researched this some before posting, and all the Kiosk-mode instructions I've seen is that it's not built into android itself: you have make low-level changes to the OS, and even then you still need to include support for it in the App. If one of the existing apps has support for this, I'd love to hear more details about it. If there is better kiosk support in a newer version of android, then pointing me to a tablet that ships with that version and is closer to the $200 price point than $500 would be great, too.

Comment: While shopping reco's... you know that part. As for "Is there an app for X" (also off-topic), you could check with [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). As for "how can I achieve this generally", your question is still fine here IMHO. I didn't dive into this topic, so all I can give are the hints I gave, sorry. Good luck, though!

Comment: @Izzy Thanks. Personally, I think the whole "shopping recommendation" ban is a mistake made by the community early... the ban _might_ make sense on Stack Overflow itself, and maybe Super User (imagine all the PC builds). Aside from that, I think the SE engine and people would be great at this. The only real problem is one that's already addressed: duplicates. Aggressively close shopping dupes, and I think there's some value to be had in opening this up... especially in smaller sites that are looking to grow the audience.

Comment: Nope. The real problem with shopping recos is: a device fine and up-to-date today is completely outaged a year later, especially when it comes to tech (you wouldn't buy a 2012 Android device today, would you?). While solutions we try to give are usually valid for several years at least. But that has been discussed elsewhere, and we shouldn't discuss it here in the comments (feel free to drop into chat for that instead).